# IComparable vs Equals() confused on which one to use

Tags: c#, generics, interface, compare

I have a class that implements `T` where `T` is an interface.

I realised I couldn't do `==` on the object so I used `Equals()` method in my code:

```
return (Equals(_nodes[node.QueueIndex] , node));
```

But after some googling, I also find `IComparable` is an option so I can also do:

```
return node.CompareTo(_nodes[node.QueueIndex]) >= 0;
```

Where by my interface inherits `IComparable` and implements it:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    return obj == this ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I am really confused on which is the correct design approach here. Do they actually serve different purposes, which one is the correct choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Equals` (or `IEquatable`) is for testing *equality*. `IComparable` is for testing for *greater than, less than, or equal to*.

There exists cases where it makes sense to test for equality, but there's no intuitive way of comparing them. For example, a `ChessPiece` class in a chess game.

I don't think `IComparable` is a good choice here because the way you implement `CompareTo` is quite awkward:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    return obj == this ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You are still just testing for equality here, not actually comparing the objects. If you can write a proper `CompareTo` method that doesn't break these [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2#notes-to-implementers), then `IComparable` is a valid choice.

Out of those rules linked, your `CompareTo` breaks this rule:

> If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns a value other than zero, then `B.CompareTo(A)` must return a value of the opposite sign.

So `Equals` would be more suitable here.

Comment: Yeah i thought requiring an int was unusual its what led me to ask :) Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

### IComparable Interface

> Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value
>   type or class implements to **order or sort its instances**.

### IEquatable Interface

> Defines a generalized method that a value type or class implements to
>   create a type-specific method **for determining equality of instances**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is usually used for things that can be ordered.

Equals is used when you want to check for equality.

If you want ordering then comparable is the way to go else use equals interface

However if you do implement comparable then do ensure that the equals interface is consistent with it.